Absolute Difference between two iid Censored Poisson Draws
Let $Y, Y' \sim Poisson \left( \lambda, C \right)$, where $\lambda$ is the mean and $C$ is some upper censoring limit. In this censored Poisson distribution, the probability mass beyond $C$ in an uncensored Poisson distribution is aggregated at $C$. Thus, the probability of $Y = C$ accounts for $P(Y > C)$ in the uncensored case.
I'm interested in $E \left[Y - Y'\right]$, i.e. the absolute difference between two iid draws from $Poisson \left( \lambda, C \right)$.
For an uncensored Poisson Distribution, this can be calculated in a closed form by using modified Bessel functions, as $E \left[Y - Y'\right] = 2 \lambda^{-2 \lambda} \{ I_{0} \left( 2 \lambda \right) + I_{1} \left( 2 \lambda \right)\}$ as derived in Katti (1960), Moments of the Absolute Difference and Absolute Deviation of Discrete Distributions.
My question is, is there a closed form expression for $E \left[Y - Y'\right]$ in the censored case? Any insights, references, or approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Well, the first step would be to find the unclosed expression:
Let $X\sim\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda)$ so that $\mathsf P(Y\mathop =k)=\mathsf P(X\mathop =k)\mathbf 1_{k\mathop \in[[0,C-1]]}+\mathsf P(X\geq C)\mathbf 1_{k\mathop=C}$
$\def\abs#1{\lvert #1\rvert}
~\begin{align}
\mathsf E(\abs{Y\mathop-Y'})&={\mathsf E(0;Y\mathop{=}Y')+\mathsf E(C;\abs{Y\mathop-Y'}\mathop{=}C)\\+\mathsf E(\abs{Y\mathop-Y'};\abs{Y\mathop-Y'}\mathop{\in}\,[[1,C\mathop-1]])}
\\[2ex]&={2C\,\mathsf P(X\mathop=0)\,\mathsf P(X\mathop\geq C)\\+2\sum_{k=1}^{C-1}k\left(\sum_{i=0}^{C-k-1}\mathsf P(X\mathop=i)\mathsf P(X\mathop=i\mathop+k)+\mathsf P(X\mathop=C\mathop-k)\mathsf P(X\mathop\geq C)\right)}
\\[2ex] &=2\mathrm e^{-2\lambda}\left(C\sum_{j=C}^\infty\dfrac{\lambda^j}{j!}+\sum_{i=0}^{C-2}\dfrac{\lambda^{2i}}{i!}\sum_{k=1}^{C-1-i}\dfrac{\lambda^{k}}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k=1}^{C-1}\dfrac{\lambda^k}{(k-1)!}\cdot\sum_{\ell=C}^\infty\dfrac{\lambda^\ell}{\ell!}\right)
\end{align}$
Which, does not look promising for closure.
